# Pandas DataFrame bitwise "&" operation on multi-columns

Tags: python, pandas

I discover the following behavior by accident with Pandas, does anyone know why the output has 6 columns instead of 3?

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[np.nan,1,1], col2=[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], col3=[1,1,1]))
dfb = pd.DataFrame(dict(col4=[1,np.nan,1], col5=[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], col6=[np.nan,1,np.nan]))

# output
dfa.isnull() & dfb.notnull()
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
0   False   False   False   False   False   False
1   False   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   False   False   False   False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is different columns names so it working like reindex by union of both columns names, in another words like another missing rows are added with `False` values:

```
c = dfa.columns.union(dfb.columns)
m = (dfa.isnull().reindex(c, fill_value=False, axis=1) & 
     dfb.notnull().reindex(c, fill_value=False, axis=1))
print (m)
    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

**Details**:

```
print (dfa.isnull().reindex(c, fill_value=False, axis=1))
    col1  col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
0   True  True  False  False  False  False
1  False  True  False  False  False  False
2  False  True  False  False  False  False

print (dfb.notnull().reindex(c, fill_value=False, axis=1))
    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6
0  False  False  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False   True  False  False
```

If change them to same get 3 columns:

```
dfb.columns = dfa.columns
m = dfa.isnull() & dfb.notnull()
print (m)
    col1   col2   col3
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

Solution with rename columns by dictionary:

```
d = dict(zip(dfb.columns, dfa.columns))
m = dfa.isnull() & dfb.rename(columns=d).notnull()
print (m)
    col1   col2   col3
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

If always same length in both DataFrames is possible convert one of them to numpy array:

```
m = dfa.isnull() & dfb.notnull().to_numpy()
print (m)
    col1   col2   col3
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```